# Triples of positive integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, logic

Prove that there is only a finite number of triples of $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\gcd(a,b) = c$, $\text{lcm}(a,c)=b$, and $a^n + b^n = c^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Thank you for the help and advice.

Comment: Fermat's Last Theorem???

Comment: No! This is specifically saying, $[a,b]=c$ and $(a,c)=b$. Fermat´s theorem does not have that condition. This condition makes the question a bit easier though some how related to Fermat´s theorem.

Comment: @ChristFANATIC for SOME $n$ or ALL $n$?

Comment: If $a=Ac$, $b=Bc$ then $A^n+B^n=1$.

Comment: @GudsonChou, there are no negative integers for $n$ but for $a,b,c$ they are allowed.

Comment: @Element118, I had confused the question with another. That constraint of $a,b,c \le 100$ is not supposed to be there.

Comment: Are these conditions even possible?  the gcd condition implies $a=Ac,\;b=Bc$ with $A,B$ relatively prime but the lcm condition implies $b=Bc=ka=kAc\;\implies\;kA=B$ whence $A$ divides $B$.  Since $A,B$ are relatively prime we must have $A=±1$ which implies $c=±b$, which makes the desired equation impossible.

Comment: As $c$ is the greatest common divisor of $a, b$, $c$ is automatically positive as $c$ cannot be $0$ (else $a=b=0$, which is trivial), and if $c<0$ we can have $-c$ as the greatest common divisor. Likewise, if $b$ is not constrained to be positive, the lowest common multiple can be $-k|ac|$ for some large positive integer $k$.